# Can I make the boot even more verbose than loglevel=7 using kernel parameters?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, grub, kernel-parameters

I have an error when booting on a machine, my machine is stuck with the error message:

`Booting a command list`.

I can see this message when I add `loglevel=7` and only if I delete the `quiet` in the kernel parameters via `grub` boot loader.

Is there a way to make the boot even more verbose than `loglevel=7` using kernel parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be stuck during loading kernel or initrd, try adding `insmod progress` line before `linux` and something like `echo 'Loading linux...'` and `echo 'Loading initrd...'` before `linux` and `initrd` lines. Also consider adding `tsc=unstable` kernel parameter, it may fix delay before booting, see following question: [kernel boot logging causes delay](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/609083/kernel-boot-logging-causes-delay)
The most verbose option should be `ignore_loglevel` , see [kernel parameters list](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt) :

> ignore_loglevel [KNL]
> Ignore loglevel setting - this will print /all/
> kernel messages to the console. Useful for debugging.
> We also add it as printk module parameter, so users
> could change it dynamically, usually by
> /sys/module/printk/parameters/ignore_loglevel.

It should look like this:

```
[some lines here, setting root, etc.]  

insmod progress  
echo 'Loading linux...'  
linux /path/to/linux root=[your root] ro ignore_loglevel tsc=unstable  
echo 'Loading initrd...'  
initrd /path/to/initrd
```

Is drive led blinking? Also notice size displayed when loading (with `insmod progress`) should be a few MiB for the kernel and from a few MiB to around 100 for initrd. If you installed linux on usb device and booting it on old laptop (or computer) that supports booting from usb, it may be loading with speed of around 60 KiB/s or even slower so it appears to be stuck (ie. with big initrd). It is the case for IBM ThinkPad type 2647.