# kernel boot logging causes delay

Tags: grub2, kernel-parameters

I see a very strange behaviour on some (not all) of my Linux machines. I am running Arch Linux with kernel 5.8.8-arch1-1

If I start the machine without grub loglevel parameter (or apply any from loglevel=0...6) boot stucks for ~90 seconds at "Loading initial ramdisk..." before continuing a very fast boot. Looking into the logs (journalctl -b, systemd-analyze blame etc.) shows no errors and tell a boot time of ~15 seconds - that is the time AFTER the delay. Bootlogs are identical to the machines which do not show the delay (identical Linux installation).

Then I tried parameter loglevel=7 in grub - and booting does no longer show the delay. Complete booting takes about 15 seconds - showing no issues. If I leave away grub loglevel parameter for kernel (or set it to any lower level than 7) booting shows big delay again. Is there any explanation for such a strange behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Poking into the dark I tried different grub kernel parameters I found on the web. "tsc=unstable" removes the delay for me at all selected loglevels. I do not understand why the delay depends on the selected loglevel but this fixes the issue.